# VS Code exits without displaying any output when a character array is taken as input

Tags: c++, arrays, input, character, cin

I have tried updating my g++ installation but there has been no solution.
Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string>
#include <cstring>
int main()
{
    char str[100];

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin>>str;
    cout << "You entered: " << str << endl;

    cout << "\nEnter another string: ";
    cin>>str;
    cout << "You entered: "<<str<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output that this code shows is:
[Check the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaTIe.png)

Please give me a solution or at least a reason for this. I am new to Stack Overflow so please free to correct me if I made any mistake in the post. [This problem only happens in vs code but works in online gdb compiler.]

Edit:After I tried executing this in the cmd line this what it shows

[cmd line execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpb0f.png)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error as such it's just not executing. No output at all/

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The output you're seeing is from some kind of makefile. You didn't say how you're trying to build the file so it's hard to say what caused the issue.

However, you can simply compile your file directly by typing `g++ hgg.cpp -o hgg` in the command shell

Comment: Umm I use the code runner extension for the  execution of the file.

Comment: And i tried what u said but its giving the same result my g++ version is 11.2.0

Comment: I almost feels as if your GCC installation might be defective because running it straight from the command line is about as close to the wire as you can get. I would simply re-install the GCC suite if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

After writing the code, switch to `Command Prompt` (`Cntrl` + `x`) move to the directory, in which the `C++` program is present.

Then run the following:

```
g++ -Wall filename.cpp -o filename
```

If nothing is printed on the console, then your code is syntactically correct. Then do the following:

```
filename.exe
```

It should work now.